# If the sum of the whole column is zero, then change the value of each row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, case

I have a column named `Percentage` from a temporary table `info`, which if the sum of the whole column is zero, I want to change the value of each row to 0.5, and if the statement is false just leave it that way.

I have tried to do the following:

```
select case when Percentage = 0 then replace(Percentage, 0,0.5) end from ##info
```

I know the above will change the fields whenever they are 0 regardless of the sum of the whole column, and if I do:

```
select case when sum(Percentage) = 0 then replace(Percentage, 0,0.5) end from ##info
```

it would throw an error.

Another thing is that I want to replace the temporary table with that column and the above code would only give me the actual column without replacing the original column.

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY` ... `SELECT Id, CASE WHEN SUM(Precentage) = 0 THEN 0.5 END ... GROUP BY Id`. Also when you got an error please post it.

Comment: Thanks, @sami. And how would I update with that value the existing table?

Comment: Use it as a subquery and join it with your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select it:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT SUM(Percentage) FROM ##info) = 0 THEN .5
        ELSE Percentage
    END
FROM ##info
```

If you want to update the values in the table:

```
 UPDATE ##info
 SET Percentage = .5
 WHERE (SELECT SUM(Percentage) FROM ##info) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find below answer.

```
declare @v_val numeric(12,2), @v_new_val numeric(12,2)

set @v_val = 0.00    
set @v_new_val = 100

select case when @v_val ='0.00' then @v_new_val else @v_val end
```